# Removing Leading Underscores from SRV Queries

Tags: java, regex

Given a domain name from a SRV query, I want to remove the leading underscores but preserve any interior underscores there might be. The domain names usually look like this:

```
_sipfederationtls._tcp.foo.com
```

I want the underscores removed:

```
sipfederationtls.tcp.foo.com
```

But if there are any interior underscores:

```
_sipfederationtls._tcp.foo_bar.com
```

I want them preserved:

```
sipfederationtls.tcp.foo_bar.com
```

I know I need to use replaceAll() but I'm not knowledgeable of regular expressions. Essentially I need a regular expression that represents an underscore, followed by some characters, ending with a period.

Comment: Keep it simple. 1. Split the String on '.', 2. Check each String for first character '_' and remove it, 3. Reassemble String.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had to use a regex, you can find any instance of an underscore that is not preceded by a word character.  To do so, you would use the negative lookbehind.  Because the period is not a word character, the below expression would only match "_sipfederationtls" and "_tcp" from the string "_sipfederationtls._tcp.foo_bar.com"

```
(?<!\w)_\w
```